# How can I send email from this code, I am trying to send emails from localhost xampp server

Tags: php

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST["send"])) {
  $to = $_POST["to"];
  $subject = $_POST["subject"];
  $message = $_POST["message"];
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  $headers = "From: your@email-address.com\r\n";
  if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
     echo "SUCCESS";
  } else {
     echo "ERROR";
  }
}
?>
```

This is my php code, I have a HTML form and $to, $subject, $message is the input fields of the form, the $_POST["send"] is the button through which I want to send emails after clicking that button

Comment: You can't unless you install an SMTP server or `sendmail` on your localhost.

Comment: I have edited my php.ini file and sendmail.ini according to smtp.gmail.com, so is PHPMailer is still mandatory?

Comment: It's not a requirement but it can definitely makes things easier. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/712392/2191572 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can't send emails from your `localhost` server. Get a free PHP server and upload your files using ftp. Following are some free php server providers where you can test your project.

- [000webhost](https://www.000webhost.com)
- [Infinity Free](https://infinityfree.net/)

Answer (score 0):

That's true, you can't send emails from localhost, unless you were using a VPS configured with DNS + public IP + email server;
If isn't your case, I would recommend sending emails through a SMTP server:

[PHP Mail (php.ini configuration)](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php)
[PHPMailer (library)](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

For the SMTP server you could use any provider that allows SMTP.

Comment: I have edited my php.ini file and sendmail.ini according to smtp.gmail.com, so is PHPMailer is still mandatory?

Comment: No, or you change the php.ini configuration to use a SMTP server or you use PHPMailer. It should work if your provider allows remote SMTP access.